docker volume mount missing files, replaced with asterisk
The following not work as expect:
  docker run --rm -it -v /tmp/folder/:/folder --entrypoint /bin/sh image  

In container, /folder exists but individual files that are present under /tmp/folder/ are missing and only asterisk is there.
In the container,
  ls /folder
  *


The /tmp/folder directory should have at least read and execute permissions. This can be changed by issuing the command sudo chmod o=rx /tmp/folder or sudo chmod o=rwx /tmp/folder, provided that no additional attributes or ACLs are applied.
user@legion:~$ mkdir /tmp/folder
user@legion:~$ touch /tmp/folder/cos
user@legion:~$ docker run -it --rm -v /tmp/folder:/folder ubuntu:latest
root@34e248dfb377:/# ls -l /folder
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000 0 May 13 17:25 cos

Let us know if it worked.

This turned out to be permission error. Directory need o+rx

Upvote and mark the other as accepted instead of copying the answer. What you put in the answer body can be a comment under the other answer explaining how to fix it.
